# How to use SUBMIT form to save message in Database

Tags: python, flask

I was asked to Create a simple Flask app which stores just a single text
field, On a single web page, and on which the user should see a form with the "message"
field. Below the form should be a list of existing messages in the
database. When user types something in the "message" field and submits the
form, the "message" should be saved to a table in SQLite. AND After the message is saved, user should come back to the page with the form and message list.

I am stuck at a POINT
I am not being able to SUBMIT the message
My page do retrieve messages from the database which is already stored in the database while I created it.

But Can SOMEONE please guide for the codes to SUBMIT the message filled in the form.
My message.html code is:

```
{% extends "template.html "%}
{% block content %}

    <h2>You are in the Message Page</h2>
    <br/>
    <p><h4>In this page, You can view the Existing Messages and can also Submit    your own message.</h4></p>
<br/><br/>

<h3>Enter Your Message:</h3><br/>

<form action="" method='POST'>
<dl>
    <dt>Message:
    <dd><input type="text" name=msg_msg maxlength=80  style="width:300px">*Maximum Length = 80
</dl>
<input type=submit value="Submit Message">

</form>

<h3>The Existing Messages:</h3>
{% for item in message %}
Msg_ID: <B>"{{ item.msg_id }}"</B><br/>Message: {{ item.msg_msg }} <br/><br/>
{% endfor %}



{% endblock %}



and my routes.py code for this is:


@app.route('/message')
def message():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('select msg_id, msg_msg from msg')
    message = [dict(msg_id=row[0], msg_msg=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('message.html', message=message)

@app.route('/message', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def message_1():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
    for request.form['input_msg'] = text:
        g.db = connect_db()
        cur = g.db.execute('insert into msg_msg from msg')
        message = [dict(msg_id=row[0], msg_msg=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
        g.db.close()
        return render_template('message.html', message=message)

        #error = 'Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.'
else:
#   session['logged_in'] = True
    return redirect(url_for('message'))
return render_template('message.html' , error=error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use 1 message view**

```
@app.route('/message', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def message():
    cur = db.execute('select id,msg from msg_msg')
    message = [dict(msg_id=row[0], msg_msg=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    if request.method == 'POST':

        g.db = connect_db()
        cur = g.db.execute('insert into msg_msg (msg) values (?)',request.form['input_msg'])
        message = [dict(msg_id=row[0], msg_msg=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
        g.db.close()

    return render_template('message.html' , message = message)
```

**message.html**

```
{% extends "template.html "%}
{% block content %}

<h2>You are in the Message Page</h2>
<br/>
<p><h4>In this page, You can view the Existing Messages and can also Submit    your own message.</h4></p>
<br/><br/>

<h3>Enter Your Message:</h3><br/>

<form action={{ url_for('message') }} method='POST'>
<dl>
<dt>Message:
<dd><input type="text" name=msg_msg maxlength=80  style="width:300px">
</dl>
<input type=submit value="Submit Message">

</form>

<h3>The Existing Messages:</h3>
{% for item in message %}
Msg_ID: <B>"{{ item.msg_id }}"</B><br/>Message: {{ item.msg_msg }} <br/><br/>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey I did with Your Codes
But now I am getting an error
"sqlite3.ProgrammingError
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. the current statement uses 1, and there are 25 supplied."

How do I solve this one now???/